# iframe in a phonegap app on ios 9.3.1

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe

I'm trying to show an iframe in a phonegap app on iOS 9.3.1. For some reason (hence this question) the iframe shows up on android but not on ios.

Setup:
1. on a mac, i installed PhoneGap desktop v0.3.1 and created a new app

2. in index.html i added the iframe

   ```
   <body>
       <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"  style="border-style:solid; width:750px; height:500px;"/>
       <div class="app">
           <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
           <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
           </div>
       </div>

       <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           app.initialize();
       </script>
   </body>
   ```
3. then tested on an iPad with the PhoneGap app (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/phonegap-developer/id843536693?mt=8) installed: on android it works while on ios it does not show up (i can see the border, but not the content)
4. then changed the config.xml to be more permissive

   ```
   <access origin="*" />
   <allow-intent href="*" />
   <allow-navigation href="*" />

   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
   <allow-intent href="*" />
   <allow-navigation href="*" />

   <platform name="android">
     <allow-intent href="*" />
   </platform>
   <platform name="ios">
     <allow-intent href="*" />
   </platform>
   ```

and added 
        
in index.html

5. tested again with the same result as 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open your Info.plist file from Resources->ProjectName-Info.plist.

Add below details:
App Transport Security Settings as Dictionary and add Allow Arbitrary Loads to true.

Check underneath image:

[image]

And second thing you need to add External Hosts as a string with item 0 having * value. Check below images:

[image]

Comment: hmm, so the problem really is with the PhoneGap developer app that can be installed from itunes

Comment: for this to work, one needs to really build a new app, not just use the generic phonegap app as that does not have all the necessary permissions

Comment: After i read your response, i tried again to build and run the app on the ipad and this time it worked even without changing the .plist file.
Just for reference: this is what cordova generates inside the .plist file:
       <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
       <true/>

Comment: Yes I know what iOS generates inside. And you can give permission using cordova project also.