# iframe appears blank on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe

I have an `iframe` that opens a page with an ad.

```
<iframe frameborder=0 height=100% marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 scrolling=no seamless src="http://pad.ample.pw/ad1/ad1.php" style=margin:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;border:0 width=100%></iframe>
```

However, when I open it on the iPhone. It's blank.

Is there something preventing iOS from displaying this frame?

Note:
If you open the url outside of an iframe it redirects elsewhere. In my case will redirect to a FB page.

Comment: This might help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835993/iframe-in-a-phonegap-app-on-ios-9-3-1

Answer (score 0):

The attributes in ur iframe element aren't into quotes. 
For example, it should be

> < iframe style="margin : 0px ; padding : 0px ">

and so on. 
Since your syntax is wrong, the html wont render properly.

Comment: Its not wrong. Its just minimized. Works in safari...on the mac.